# How to get the rating only from the imdb database?

Tags: javascript, imdb

I cannot understand how to get rating from the database of `IMDB` from https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/. How do I construct a url to get the rating of the film `Iron Man (2008)`. Also is it free to use `IMDB` data onto your website.

Comment: http://www.omdbapi.com/

Comment: IMDB does not have a public API available but you can use third party API e.g. http://omdbapi.com/ (as mentioned by @ptts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.theimdbapi.com/# you can use this api, which is very easy and reliable